# Using Furk.net API doesn't keep me logged in

Tags: php, api, curl

I am using the [Furk.net API](https://www.furk.net/t/api) and I have managed to successfully login using a curl function and submitting the post data to the proper URL (http://api.furk.net/api/login/login). When I echo the results, I get a success message and the cookie is successfully stored on my server. However, when I try to then retrieve information from the API, it gives me access denied. I'm wondering why my cookie isn't being used for all following requests?

```
function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') {
    global $megauser;
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
}

$login_data = array(
    'login' => 'user',
    'pwd' => 'pass'
);

echo getUrl('http://api.furk.net/api/login/login','post', $login_data);
```

If I try another request on the API using this same function while the cookie exists, I get access denied, but if I try the same request in my browser while logged in, I get the appropriate results.

Answer (score 3):

When you login, you don't need to save the cookie. You will receive an answer from the API with the apy_key.
You need to keep that key, and send it along with all your other requests to the API (As as POST parameter)

And you should not use the cookie and the api_key at the same time, as some requests are denied if both are sent.